# SIGABRT on start

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sigabrt

I'm getting a SIGABRT error when my app starts. It reads:

```
2011-07-19 14:01:51.321 App[364:707] -[AppViewController handle_VolumeChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x25d400
2011-07-19 14:01:51.386 App[364:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppViewController handle_VolumeChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x25d400'
```

I'm clueless as to why it's crashing. There isn't a `handle_VolumeChanged` anywhere in my code. Because of my app I don't want to have it. Is it required?

Comment: Can you post the line of code where the app crashes?

Comment: It must be somewhere. Do a Shift-Cmd-F to search for `handle_VolumeChanged`.

Comment: Are you attempting to change the volume of the device programmatically? If so, don't.

Comment: I figured it out, it was really dumb xD I had a method called handle_volumeChanged instead of handle_VolumeChanged

Comment: You should move your last comment there to an answer, and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. It was solved by reseting my IOS device. Open the IOS simulator and go to iOS Simulator->Reset Content and Settings. This may work if you are positive the problem is not your code.